# How can I set pre-defined installation path, not user defined?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, installation

How can I set a pre-defined installation path (not user defined) in my setup in Visual Studio 2008 (C#)
I don't need that the user selects/chooses the installation folder because I want to set a predefined installation path. Please help me.

Comment: Your users may disagree that they don't need to be able to choose the location.

Comment: +1 to Andrew's comment. It's a pretty fragile application if it relies on a specific installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you should, but try something like this (from VS 2010 Setup Project, not sure if the same or not)

Right-Click your Setup project and go to `View -> File System`

Set the `Application Folder`'s `DefaultLocation` Property to your desired location (`[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`)

Right-Click your Setup project and go to `View -> User Interface`

Delete out the `Installation Folder` Dialog